# Non-trivial vector field with divergence $0$ on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a non-trivial vector field $X$ on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the induced metric such that its divergence is $0$. I recall here the expresion of the divergence of a vector field in a chart:
$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\Rightarrow \mathrm{Div}X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial(X_{i}\sqrt{|g|})}{\partial x_{i}},
$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the matrix of the metric $(g_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example would be to simply rotate the sphere:

$$ X(x,y,z) = (-y,x,0) $$

(This considers the sphere to be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, and has values in the induced representation of the tangent space at each point. I'll leave it to you to represent it in a two-dimensional chart of your choice).

Comment: A field is of divergence 0 iff its flow preserve area. Let $A$ be any $(3,3) $ skew symmetric matrix. The field $X(p)=A.p$ satisfies this property as it flow is $exp tA$ an orthogonal transformation hence isometry of the 3-sphere.

Comment: @Thomas: Is that a comment to the question or to my answer?

Comment: Both : that there is no need to represent the field in a chart to check that it is divergence free .

Comment: @Thomas: Oh, I agree about that. It just looked like the OP _wanted_ to verify it using a chart.

Comment: If you use a chart, just take $X= i{ \nabla} f$ vert $i$ is the rotation of angle $\pi/2$. This will be easier, and you will not see any sphere around